# Rapidminer Web Crawling doesn't store sites (Kickstarter)

Tags: web-crawler, rapidminer

I'm working on a web crawling project to analyse various crowdfunding sites' projects via text mining in Rapidminer 5/6. I have already built a working text analyser, but I'm stuck at the web crawling part. The problem is that the web crawler does crawl through the requested sites, but doesn't store them. I have tried experimenting with page size, depth and the like, but still the program just skips those sites. It is probable that the problem is with my storing rules. They look like the following, when trying to crawl through Kickstarter's sites:

Follow with matching URL:

.+kickstarter.+

Store with matching URL:

```
https://www\.kickstarter\.com\/projects.+

http://www\.kickstarter\.com\/projects.+

(?i)http.*://www\.kickstarter\.com\/projects.+
```

An example URL that would need to be stored is:

```
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/corvuse/bhaloidam-an-indie-tabletop-storytelling-game?ref=spotlight
```

(no advertising intended)

And the log looks like the following:

```
Mar 12, 2014 11:50:37 AM INFO: Following link http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/corvuse/bhaloidam-an-indie-tabletop-storytelling-game?ref=spotlight
Mar 12, 2014 11:50:37 AM INFO: Following link http://kickstarter.tumblr.com/post/12036057734/todays-project-of-the-day-is-bhaloidam-an-indie
Mar 12, 2014 11:50:37 AM INFO: Following link http://kickstarter.tumblr.com/tagged/bhaloidam
Mar 12, 2014 11:50:38 AM INFO: Discarded page "http://kickstarter.tumblr.com/post/79165806431/do-you-like-coloring-and-also-have-questions" because url does not match filter rules.
```

As you can see, it follows through with the process and just skips these links, and it doesn't even say that it doesn't match the filter rules so it's been discarded, so I'm not even sure that in these cases the program compares the links to the rules. I see a lot of links in the log preceded with ("Following link..") but very few preceded with ("Discarded page..."). Does this mean that it just checks a few pages, or just that it won't notify me for every discarded page? I am able to save these projects' sites manually, but understandibly, I wouldn't like to do this with hundreds of sites.

I've also built a model for Indiegogo, and the same model works if I use only the third storing rule (and remove the first two). So I thought this is also the problem with my Kickstarter model, but no luck this way either.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one store rule. That's why it works when you only have the third regex alone. You can however combine your three store regexes into one:

```
https://www\.kickstarter\.com\/projects.+|http://www\.kickstarter\.com\/projects.+|(?i)http.*://www\.kickstarter\.com\/projects.+
```

Interesting project, btw. Would be great if you could drop us a mail and tell us more about it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that (using only the third rule), but sadly, neither that, nor your solution works, it still just skips these sites. I get no message about storing or discarding the pages. Thanks anyway!


About the project, it's really not a big deal. I'm working on my thesis now regarding some crowdfunding projects and decided to give it some IT edge by building a model that analyses the sites by topic (mostly just occurence of some keywords, like "art", "business", "technology" or "music") through tokenizing, stopword filtering, stemming and other basic text mining operators.